# changing the color of surfaceview using buttons in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

I'm trying to change the color or background of a surfaceview using buttons to change from different colors. I've gone online and seen a lot that tells me to use onClick="changeblue" in the XML and create a simple method "changeblue" that will change the color of the surfaceview but for some reason it cant find the surfaceview background color or just surfaceview color. any ideas?
 [image]

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Color Change App"
    android:id="@+id/txt"
    android:textSize="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Changes to blue"
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#aeb3b5"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:textColor="#1b28b8"
    android:onClick="btn1"
    android:enabled="false" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change to green"
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#aeb3b5"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:textColor="#098c07"
    android:onClick="btn2"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Changes to white"
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#aeb3b5"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:onClick="btn3"/>

<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
package com.example.nathan.colorchangeapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void btn1(View view) {
    //change color of surfaceview to blue
    SurfaceView.//no background or color option
}
public void btn2(View view) {
    //change color of surfaceview to green
}
public void btn3(View view) {
    //change color of srufaceview to white
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. btn1,btn2,btn3, and surfaceView are the id's on the XML page. i found not to use a onclick on the XML as well.

```
package com.example.nathan.colorchange;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button bluebtn, greenbtn, whitebtn;
SurfaceView SView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bluebtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    greenbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    whitebtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    SView=(SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);


    bluebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        SView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    });
    greenbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    });
    whitebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```